# Android Layout Manager scaling images

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using the Linear Layout Manager and I am trying to use the image width and height (wrapContent) automatically within the application. However, all of the images are appearing larger than what they should be. I think I know why: If I put an image that is 320X480 on the screen, on my device that has a pixel resolution of 480X800, it fills up the entire screen. This results in all of my images being too big for this screen, as I am building my images for a screen size that is 480X800.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: fix the height of the imageview

Answer (score -1):

u can use absolute layout!
and can set the width and heigth of the image as u want!

go to the layout xml page and then change it to Absolute layout.
then you can easily change the the width .. 
right click -> property

set the height and wigth as u like... Eg:"120dip"
it will solve your issue..
if not let me know will provide you another alternative